# Python 'No such file or directory' opening path `~/filename` with mode `w+`

Tags: python, error-handling, ioerror

I'm trying to open a file that doesn't exist with this line:

```
x = open("~/tweetly/auth", 'w+')
```

That should open it if it exists, and then wipe content to begin to write.
If it doesn't exist, it should create it...right?

It doesn't. I get this error.

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/tweetly/auth'
```

Ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the path `~/tweetly/` exists and is being resolved correctly?

Comment: checked it myself. I'm executing it from the user `tekknolagi` therefore it should resolve to `/home/tekknolagi/...` right?

Comment: Depends if it thinks `~` is the user's home directory. I didn't that would work in this context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `~` alias for the home directory is a shell-ism (something the shell does for you), not something you can use with the Python `open` command:

```
pax:~$ cd ~

pax:~$ ls qq.s
qq.s

pax:~$ python
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:05:24) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> open("~/qq.s")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/qq.s'

>>> open("./qq.s")
<open file './qq.s', mode 'r' at 0xb7359e38>

>>> _
```

Comment: points freebie for you :P i can't accept this for two minutes >:(

Answer (score 4):

While it's true that Python's `open` does not support `~` expansion directly, you can use it in conjunction with the Python standard library function [os.path.expanduser](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.expanduser("~/qq.s")
'/Users/nad/qq.s'
>>> open(os.path.expanduser("~/qq.s"), 'w+')
<open file '/Users/nad/qq.s', mode 'w+' at 0x1049ef810>
```

Comment: Hey, that's _damn_ handy, I didn't even know about that one. +1.

Comment: And it's supported on all Python platforms including Windows.

Comment: like this :) great use of `os`